# Saving user data for frontend app

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm developing a front-end app with Backbone. On the app start a service call where I get some  user related data - numbers, currency, dateFormat and similar stuff. I have to  save this data  for future uses. the question is - where? It can be local  storage - but its purpose is  a bit different or some singleton Backbone Model. Are there better options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local storage is a useful tool for persisting data *between* user sessions. However you are suggesting that when the user first accesses the (single-page) application, a service call is made to retrieve user related data (something akin to a user profile I'd imagine, a profile pic, locale settings and user preferences).

This means there's no need to persist the data in the browser beyond any loaded javascript objects. The singleton model is a common pattern to tackle this.

For a good example on how to great a singleton Backbone model see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9825238/1084004